# SQL most commonly occurring

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to find out, which actors are mostly playing in comedy movies.
The majority of their filmography have to be comedy.

So when a actor has 7 movies and 4 of them are comedy.

(And also all actors who only have played comedies.)

Table "actor":

```
|id_actor| name |
|--------|------|
|  12    |franco|
|  13    |rogen |
|  14    |hill  |
|  15    |teller|
|  16    |john  |
```

Table "genre"

```
|id_genre|    name    |
|--------|------------|
|  22    |comedy      |
|  23    |thriller    |
|  24    |documentary |
```

Table "plays_in":

```
|id_actor|    id_film |
|--------|------------|
|  12    |      5001  |
|  12    |      5002  |
|  12    |      5003  |
|  13    |      5004  |
|  13    |      5005  |
|  13    |      5006  |
|  14    |      5007  |
|  14    |      5008  |
```

Table is_in_genre

```
|id_genre|    id_film |
|--------|------------|
|  22    |      5001  |
|  22    |      5002  |
|  22    |      5003  |
|  23    |      5004  |
|  23    |      5005  |
|  24    |      5006  |
|  24    |      5007  |
|  24    |      5008  |
```

This is what I have, but it doesn't show actors, that only played comedies.

```
select      id_actor, name 
from        actor x where
(
    select      count(id_film) 
    from        actor y
    natural join plays_in 
    natural join movie
    natural join is_in_genre
    where       id_genre = 4001 and x.id_actor = y.id_actor 
    group by    id_actor
)
<=
(
    select      count(id_film) 
    from        actor y
    natural join plays_in 
    natural join movie
    natural join is_in_genre
    where       id_genre != 4001 and x.id_actor = y.id_actor 
    group by    id_actor
)
```

Comment: Please put your schema, sample data and expected output by editing the question.

Comment: As a rule of thumb try to avoid natural joins. They are difficult to understand, and to debug.

Comment: are you looking for those who only played in Comendy and no other genre?

Comment: What does "most commonly occurring" mean?  Also, forget `natural join`.  Put the join conditions explicitly in the query.

Comment: @kamalpreet who played in Comedy and who played mostly Comedy. so more than 50%

Comment: Can `is_in_genre` contain more than one row per `id_film`? Its name suggests this (otherwise, if one row represented a film, that table would usually be called just `film`). If this table can contain multiple entries per `id_film` as I suppose, then this is something to consider in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join all 4 tables and group by actor.  
To get only actors who only played more than 50% comedies the condition after grouping is:
`having (1.0 * sum(case when genrename = 'comedy' then 1 else 0 end ) / count(genrename)) > 0.5`.

```
select 
  t.actorname
from (
select 
  actor.name actorname, genre.name genrename
from actor 
inner join plays_in
on plays_in.id_actor = actor.id_actor
inner join is_in_genre
on is_in_genre.id_film = plays_in.id_film
inner join genre
on genre.id_genre = is_in_genre.id_genre
) t
group by t.actorname
having (1.0 * sum(case when genrename = 'comedy' then 1 else 0 end ) / count(genrename)) > 0.5
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=46dabe27445be1e0055a20816e694139)

Comment: thank you, but I wanted all actors, who played mostly in comedies. (so when 4 of 7 movies are comedies)

Comment: I added data in the demo.

Comment: `is_in_genre` is obviously a bridge table between some film table and the genre table to express an n:m relation. So a movie can be a comedy thriller for instance, hence being linked to both genre comedy and thriller. Your query doesn't take this into account.

Comment: *so a movie can be a comedy thriller for instance* did you decide that? Do you see this in the sample data? Did the OP mention it?

Comment: @forpas what are the last 3 lines doing?

Comment: @matemate grouping by the actor's name and applying the condition comedies > 50%

Comment: @forpas and why do you have to multiplicate it with 1.0 ?  By the way thank you very much for your help !

Comment: @matemate a division like 13/20 would give 0 as result because the numbers are integer. By multiplying * 1.0 they are treated as real numbers.

Comment: @forpas: No, I deduct this from the table's name. A table named `is_in_genre` consisting of two columns `id_genre` and `id_film` suggests to be a bridge table between a `genre` table whose primary key is the `id_genre` and a `film` table whose primary key is `id_film`. This is a n:m relation and your query doesn't consider this. If it were a 1:n relation, the table would not be called  `is_in_genre`, but simply `film` (with `id_film` being the primary key).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner * I deduct this from the table's name* really? And why did the OP accept this answer?

Comment: Why so defensive? It may be that this is not a bridge table. That would mean that the table name or even the datamodel is inappropriate. Or it may be a bridge table and the OP is just not experienced enough to understand the impact here. We are both here to help, and I just thought I should point to this potential issue. It was not meant to criticize you.

Answer (score 0):

A movie is a comedy when one of its genres is comedy. The actors you are looking for are those whose movies are mainly comedies.

```
with comedies as
(
  select id_film
  from is_in_genre
  group by id_film
  having count(case when id_genre = (select id_genre from genre where name = 'comedy') then 1 end) > 0
)
, comedy_actors as 
(
  select id_actor
  from plays_in
  group by id_actor
  having avg(case when id_film in (select id_film from comedies) then 1 else 0 end) > 0.5
)
select *
from actor
where id_actor in (select id_actor from comedy_actors);
```